# identify this connector - faston housing

Tags: connector, wire, terminal, wire-terminals

need MFG of this connector. It is not tyco event though there are tyco fastons installed (confirmed by Tyco).
2 position faston housing. tab locks are on facing outwards.

no markings on connector

color is light gray, some sort of plastic

[image][image]

Comment: Please capitalise sentences and brand names and punctuate properly as per site guidance on [quality standards](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Answer (score 4):

That looks just like a 'blade terminal housing'.  Hella makes some that [look identical](https://www.onlinecarparts.co.uk/hella-945143.html).

[image]